# GetOpenFileName function in ms project VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-project, ms-project-server-2013

I'm trying to use the GetOpenFileName function, in vba for ms project. Is it available only in excel? no option to use it in ms project?
Thanks.

Comment: try reading here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?1029-Solved-GetOpenFilename-in-MS-Project

Comment: Tried it. It did not work.

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried, and tell us **how** it did not work.

Comment: Yes, only in Excel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865152.aspx

If it doesn't appear in autocomplete on your application object as you write your VBA code, you can be pretty sure the method doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks alot. I called an excel object within the project vba, and used the function with it.

Comment: So, are you wanting to open an .xlsx file or something in Project? For purposes of importing data? If so you don't necessarily have to spin up the Excel object. If you want to know more just say so. Sound like you are back on your way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue apparently the "GetOpenFineName" function works in Excel but is not supported in MS Projects. You will have to write it yourself.

To make it easier, below you can find code you have to copy past at the top of your program in MS project. Then you can use GetOpenFileName in the code you are writing yourself in your program.

Good luck.

```
Private Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As String
End Type

Private Const OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT = &H200
Private Const OFN_CREATEPROMPT = &H2000
Private Const OFN_EXPLORER = &H80000
Private Const OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST = &H1000
Private Const OFN_HIDEREADONLY = &H4
Private Const OFN_NOCHANGEDIR = &H8
Private Const OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS = &H100000
Private Const OFN_NONETWORKBUTTON = &H20000
Private Const OFN_NOREADONLYRETURN = &H8000
Private Const OFN_NOVALIDATE = &H100
Private Const OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT = &H2
Private Const OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST = &H800
Private Const OFN_READONLY = &H1
Private Const OFN_SHOWHELP = &H10

Private Declare Function GetOpenFileNameA Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    (OFN As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean

Private Declare Function GetSaveFileNameA Lib "comdlg32.dll" _
    (OFN As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean

Private Const ALLFILES = "All Files"

Function MakeFilterString(ParamArray varFilt() As Variant) As String
    ' Creates a filter string.
    ' Returns "" if there are no arguments.
    ' Expects an even number of argumenten (filter name, extension).
    ' Adds *.* if the number of arguments is odd.

    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim intRes As Integer
    Dim intNum As Integer

    intNum = UBound(varFilt)
    If intNum <> -1 Then
        For intRes = 0 To intNum
            strFilter = strFilter & varFilt(intRes) & vbNullChar
        Next
        If intNum Mod 2 = 0 Then
            strFilter = strFilter & "*.*" & vbNullChar
        End If

        strFilter = strFilter & vbNullChar
    End If

    MakeFilterString = strFilter
End Function

Private Sub InitOFN(OFN As OPENFILENAME)
    With OFN
        ' Initialize fields
        .hwndOwner = 0
        .hInstance = 0
        .lpstrCustomFilter = vbNullString
        .nMaxCustFilter = 0
        .lpfnHook = 0
        .lpTemplateName = 0
        .lCustData = 0
        .nMaxFile = 511
        .lpstrFileTitle = String(512, 0)
        .nMaxFileTitle = 511
        .lStructSize = Len(OFN)
        If .lpstrFilter = "" Then
            .lpstrFilter = MakeFilterString(ALLFILES)
        End If
        .lpstrFile = .lpstrFile & String(512 - Len(.lpstrFile), 0)
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessOFN(OFN As OPENFILENAME)
    With OFN
        .lpstrFile = Left$(.lpstrFile, InStr(.lpstrFile, vbNullChar) - 1)
    End With
End Sub

Private Function OpenDialog(OFN As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean
    ' Display the Open dialog.
    Dim intRes As Integer
    InitOFN OFN
    intRes = GetOpenFileNameA(OFN)
    If intRes Then
        ProcessOFN OFN
    End If
    OpenDialog = intRes
End Function

Private Function SaveDialog(OFN As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean
    ' Display the Save As dialog.
    Dim intRes As Integer
    InitOFN OFN
    intRes = GetSaveFileNameA(OFN)
    If intRes Then
        ProcessOFN OFN
    End If
    SaveDialog = intRes
End Function

Private Function GetOpenFileName(Optional FileFilter As String, Optional FilterIndex As Long, Optional Title As String = "Select a File") As String
    Dim OFN As OPENFILENAME
    With OFN
        If FileFilter <> "" Then
            .lpstrFilter = Replace(FileFilter, ",", vbNullChar) & vbNullChar
        End If
        .nFilterIndex = FilterIndex
        .lpstrTitle = Title
    End With
    If OpenDialog(OFN) Then
        GetOpenFileName = OFN.lpstrFile
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetSaveAsFileName(InitialFileName As String, Optional FileFilter As String, Optional FilterIndex As Long, Optional Title As String = "Select a File") As String
    Dim OFN As OPENFILENAME
    With OFN
        .lpstrFile = InitialFileName
        If FileFilter <> "" Then
            .lpstrFilter = Replace(FileFilter, ",", vbNullChar) & vbNullChar
        End If
        .nFilterIndex = FilterIndex
        .lpstrTitle = Title
    End With
    If SaveDialog(OFN) Then
        GetSaveAsFileName = OFN.lpstrFile
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Did you find that this method has some issues? I have used this, after scrounging off another site, and with some modification am using it for Mapping Import/Export. In doing so, I am finding that my files in export to Excel (XLSX) start showing as "Read Only" when attempting to edit them often. This leads to seemingly mapping import errors.

I have yet to resolve if something needs to be added to this to 'clean-up' use of the File and or API itself.

Is this particular code missing a CLOSE, =NOTHING, or something similar to that? Hunting online has not yet identified an answer to this.